# How do I simulate Verilog code in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

Want to execute verilog code.
Is it possible to get one with graphic interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can download SynpatiCAD using [this](http://www.syncad.com/) link.

> SynpatiCAD is a Timing Diagram Software, Verilog Simulator, Verilog
>   Compiler, & Testbench Creation